# How can I get a US Greencard through the Diversity Visa Program?

Tags: usa, working-visas, greencard

How can I win a resident visa through the Greencard Lottery? Should I go to a US Embassy or can I apply online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Diversity Visa Program (aka Green Card Lottery) is currently closed. When it is open you must apply online. Information can be found at the [US Dept of State](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/DV-2015-Instructions-Translations/DV_2015_Instructions.pdf)

> Entries for the DV-2015 DV program must be submitted electronically at www.dvlottery.state.gov
>   between noon, Eastern Daylight Time (EDT) (GMT-4), Tuesday, October 1, 2013, and noon, Eastern
>   Daylight Time (EDT) (GMT-4), Saturday, November 2, 2013. Do not wait until the last week of the
>   registration period to enter, as heavy demand may result in website delays. No late entries or paper
>   entries will be accepted. The law allows only one entry by or for each person during each registration
>   period. The Department of State uses sophisticated technology to detect multiple entries. If you submit
>   more than one entry you will be disqualified.

Answer (score 5):

In order to win you have to play.  The US Diversity Lottery applications are only electronic and are open for a short period of time.

You can read the [instructions for DV-2015](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/DV-2015-Instructions-Translations/DV_2015_Instructions.pdf) or go [DV Lottery Entrance Website](https://www.dvlottery.state.gov/).  The DV-2016 applications will be available no earlier then October 1, 2014.